# AQGridView cell data repeat issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, gridview

I'm trying to implement a 3Xn grid view and currently I'm using AQGridView classes and it is working fine but the only problem is that on scrolling the data repeats like that in tableView, in tableView I use to handle this issue using this code

```
NSUInteger row = 0; 
NSUInteger sect = indexPath.section;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sect; ++ i)
    row += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];

row += indexPath.row;
```

I was wondering if there is similar solution for this as well. This is my current code for the grid views

```
- (AQGridView *) gridView {

    if (![self isViewLoaded])
        return nil;

    AQGridView * const gv = (AQGridView *)_groupGridView;
    NSCParameterAssert([gv isKindOfClass:[AQGridView class]]);

    return gv;

}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

}


- (NSUInteger) numberOfItemsInGridView: (AQGridView *) gridView
{

    return [selectedList count];

}

- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    static NSString * const identifier = @"Cell";
    NTGridViewCell *cell = (NTGridViewCell *)[gridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell)
        NSCParameterAssert([cell isKindOfClass:[NTGridViewCell class]]);

    if (!cell) {

        CGRect cellFrame = (CGRect){
            CGPointZero,
            gridView.gridCellSize
        };

        cell = [NTGridViewCell cellFromNib];
        cell.reuseIdentifier = identifier;
        cell.frame = cellFrame;
        cell.delegate=self;

        cell.userName.text=[[selectedList objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"name"];

        NSLog(@"number:%d,name:%@",index,[[selectedList objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"name"]);

        cell.contentView.superview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;

}
```

I have 26 items in my selectedList but the log prints the number upto 11 only no matter how much I scroll and the label after 12 items repeats from start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
-(AQGridViewCell *) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
        static NSString * const identifier = @"Cell";
        NTGridViewCell *cell = (NTGridViewCell *)[gridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (cell)
            NSCParameterAssert([cell isKindOfClass:[NTGridViewCell class]]);

        if (!cell)
        {
            CGRect cellFrame = (CGRect){
                CGPointZero,
                gridView.gridCellSize
            };
            cell = [NTGridViewCell cellFromNib];
            cell.reuseIdentifier = identifier;
            cell.frame = cellFrame;
            cell.delegate=self;
        }
        cell.userName.text=[[selectedList objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"number:%d,name:%@",index,[[selectedList objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"name"]);
        cell.contentView.superview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Just one more question, currently my grid view I also have a button. and I have set its tag like cell.button.tag=[[[selectedList objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"uniqueId"] intValue]; and in its delegate i have -(void)onDeleteButtonTouched:(NTGridViewCell *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Selected Button:%d",sender.tag);
} but this always returns Selected Button:0, any advice?

Comment: In each cell there is a button which triggers this method -(void)onDeleteButtonTouched:(NTGridViewCell *)sender { NSLog(@"Selected Button:%d",sender.tag); } in my cellForItemAtIndex i have added  cell.deleteButton.tag=[[[selectedList objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"uniqueId"] intValue]; after assigning cell.userName.text. I'm trying to delete the cell with the corresponding uniqueId on which the delete button is clicked. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue, actually in button action it should be sender.deleteButton.tag